# ts plot with seaborn returns exception

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, time-series, seaborn

I am trying to make a timeseries plot with Seaborn.

My data is:

```
plot_data
Deflated_Index_Norm CCI_Norm    BCI_Norm    Date
0   1.0 1.000000    1.0 1989-01-01
1   1.0 1.009339    1.0 1989-01-01
2   1.0 0.992044    1.0 1989-01-01
3   1.0 1.007378    1.0 1989-01-01
4   1.0 0.998444    1.0 1989-01-01
5   1.0 0.990092    1.0 1989-01-01
6   1.0 1.001803    1.0 1989-01-01
7   1.0 0.993946    1.0 1989-01-01
8   1.0 0.993131    1.0 1989-01-01
9   1.0 0.999931    1.0 1989-01-01

plot_data.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 10 entries, 0 to 9
Data columns (total 4 columns):
Deflated_Index_Norm    10 non-null float64
CCI_Norm               10 non-null float64
BCI_Norm               10 non-null float64
Date                   10 non-null datetime64[ns]
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(3)
memory usage: 400.0 bytes

import seaborn as sns
sns.tsplot(data = plot_data, time = 'Date')

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I don't understand the meaning of the error message.

Comment: you don't want `tsplot`. read its docs to find out why. you want `lineplot`